# How to create a header and side bar in a single page using angular2

Tags: angular

I created a header and a side bar separately using Angular 2. The question I want to integrate them as a single one. I want to create them in a single page.

Comment: Please include the code you've written so far. The more details you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Having the header menu bar as below

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector:'header-bar',
    template: `
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                ..........
          </div>
        </nav>

     `


})
export class HeaderBarComponent{


}
```

Having the side bar as below

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector:'side-bar',
    template: `
        <div>
            .................
        </div>

     `


})
export class SideBarComponent{


}
```

Your AppComponent should have

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector:'app',
    template: `
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                    <header-bar> </header-bar>
            </div>              
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                    <side-bar> </side-bar>
            </div>              
            <div class="col-md-3">
                    ..main content goes here
                    <router-outlet> </router-outlet>
            </div>              
        </div>

     `


})
export class AppComponent{


}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create navbar component (NavbarComponent)  selector : 'navbar'
2. Create sidebar component (SidebarComponent) , selector : 'sidebar'
3. At your app.html :

   ```
   <div class="row">
       <navbar> </navbar>             
   </div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
              <sidebar> </sidebar>
       </div>              
       <div class="col-md-9">
               <router-outlet> </router-outlet>
       </div>              
   </div>
   ```
4. you need to add to your app.module the new component at declarations.

   ```
   declarations: [NavbarComponent, SidebarComponent],
   ```